# Trying to save all generated 'li' elements to local storage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This code successfully takes the contents of the form and saves it to an ordered list, 2 more functions do the same thing but instead create a timestamp. I'm trying to take every `li` element that gets generated and save it to `localStorage` when you push the save button and then repopulate it again from the local storage when you push the "load" button. I can't get it to work come hell or high water. The load button does nothing, and oddly enough the "save" button acts as a clear all and actually removes everything rather then saving it. Console log shows no errors. I have the JavaScript below and the corresponding HTML.

```js
let item;
let text;
let newItem;

function todoList() {
  item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
  text = document.createTextNode(item)
  newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  }
  newItem.onmousemove = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  }
  newItem.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  }
  todoInput.onclick = function() {
    this.value = ""
  }
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
};


function save() {
  const fieldvalue = querySelectorAll('li').value;
  localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(item));
}

function load() {


  const storedvalue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item));


  if (storedvalue) {
    document.querySelectorAll('li').value = storedvalue;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput" value="" size="15" placeholder="enter task here">
  <button id="button" type="button" onClick="todoList()">Add task</button>
  <button id="save" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  <button id="load" onclick="load()">Load</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll('li').value` will be `undefined` because `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`

Comment: It looks like the load function does nothing because you have item rather than 'item'. Try using "use strict" mode to see the errors.  Also, you're using querySelectorAll which returns an array of li elements, not just one.  Thus, you cannot use value on an array.  You have to loop through the result and get the value of each element separately and then save them with a unique key or save the enitre set under a single key.

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil and @Gary explained part of your problem is trying to use querySelectorAll('li') as if it would return a single value. You have to cycle through the array it returns.

Check the below code to give yourself a starting point. I had to rename some of your functions since they were causing me some errors.

```
<form id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput" value="" size="15" placeholder="enter task here">
  <button id="button" type="button" onClick="todoList()">Add task</button>
  <button id="save" onclick="saveAll()" type="button">Save</button>
  <button id="load" onclick="loadAll()" type="button">Load</button>
</form>

<div id="todoList"></div>

<script>
  let item;
  let text;
  let newItem;

  function todoList() {
    item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
    text = document.createTextNode(item)
    newItem = document.createElement("li")

    newItem.onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
    newItem.onmousemove = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
    newItem.onmouseout = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }
    todoInput.onclick = function() {
      this.value = ""
    }

    newItem.appendChild(text)
    //Had to add the element
    document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
  }


  function saveAll() {

    //Create an array to store the li values
    var toStorage = [];

    var values = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    //Cycle through the li array
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      toStorage.push(values[i].innerHTML);
    }

    console.log(toStorage);
    //Can´t test this on stackoverflow se the jsFiddle link
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(toStorage));
    console.log(localStorage);

  }

  function loadAll() {

    const storedvalue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    console.log(storedvalue);
        //Load your list here
  }

</script>
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/nbe18k2u/ to see it working